# Problem with drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 yesterday on my Dell Insipron 15 7567 (previously had Windows 10) and system seems to have a lot of issues.

- Audio quality is very poor (even after installing alsamixer). And the audio seems to be predominantly playing from left speaker only.
- Video flickers during playback.
- Blender is not recognizing my NVIDIA card for gpu accelerated rendering.

I read a bunch of discussions on AskUbuntu, but nothing seems to work out.
Please help...

Comment: And also during videoplayback (in media player  and youtube as well), the UI momentarily freezes and I hear a buzzing sound from my speaker.